# sql search between date Error

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I want to retrieve data between two specific date and I am getting that perfectly right with this query

`select * from POS.dbo.voucher where date_time between '10 october 2014 00.00.00 ' and  '11 october 2014 12.00.00'`

but the issue is if I'm changing the month something like

`select * from POS.dbo.voucher where date_time between '10 march 2014 00.00.00 ' and  '11 march 2014 12.00.00'`

It's still returning me with the same records. Seems like its only comparing the date and returning me the records.

Any idea where i m doing it wrong?

I am taking date as varchar in database.

Thanks!!

Comment: Better to use the simple date format YYYYMMDD - 1991-01-30 12:00:00 . You can change 00.00.00 to 00:00:00 then try if there will be a change.

Comment: First of all you have to decide which database are you using: Mysql or MSSQL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using SQL Server (based on the `dbo`).  Use a standard date format for date constants:

```
select *
from POS.dbo.voucher
where date_time between '2014-10-10 00:00:00' and '2014-10-11 12:00:00'
```

However, for this to work, you need to store dates using proper date formats in the database.  So, you should fix the data structure to store dates using the correct data type.

Answer (score 0):

I agree you would be better off changing the field from varchar to datetime. If that's not an option then you should convert the varchar field in the query into a datetime as appropriate in MS SQL Server, probably through a function, perhaps through a cast. BTW, best to tag with actually db used, and maybe SQL too.